# Instagram redirect URI doesn't match or some time safari says "Cannot open because invalid address" + iOS native app

Tags: ios, redirect, uri, instagram, invalid-url

I'm using this iOS Library https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk to login to instagram from my native app for sharing and getting feed from Instagram APIs. When i brought classes from this demo app to my project, here it is what happens:

Application successfully opens Authorization URL in safari and when i enter my credentials & authorize, it says "Safari cannot open address because its invalid" before redirecting to app or some time says "Redirect URI does not match registered URI".

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add URL scheme to your application's plist file, it's mentioned in short guide on github instragram page:
Make sure you've edited your application's .plist file properly, so that your applicaition binds to the `ig[clientId]://` URL scheme (where `[clientId]` is your Instagram application CLIENT ID).

Here you'll find more information, see this article on [TutsPlus: iOS SDK Working With URL Schemes](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/)

Comment: I still didn't figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: So the URL scheme should look like this ig[clientID] and NOT ig[clientID]://

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that the URI you gave it is not handled by anything in the phone.

For example - the skype uri looks like   skype:
IF skype is installed, it opens skype.
If skype is NOT installed, you get that same error.

You are either using the wrong URI (probably because you got the client-id wrong - do not include the [] in it), or, you do not have the Instagram app installed on your iOS device, or possibly you've messed with your instagram account and the app is not listening to that URI anymore.